# PostgreSQL - return a single row when querying using a json function

Tags: postgresql

We're storing state transition data in a json column like this:

```
state: {
  current_state: 'state_three',
  transitions: [
    { from: 'state_two', to: 'state_three', at: [time in iso8601] },
    { from: 'state_one', to: 'state_two', at: [time in iso8601] }
  ]
}
```

On occasion we need to query for rows that were in some state before some time, so we have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table, json_array_elements("my_table"."state"->'transitions') as state_changes
  WHERE ((state_changes->>'to' = 'state_two')
    AND (state_changes->>'at' < '2016-04-11 00:00:00.000000'))
```

The issue with this query is that in certain cases we may transition to the state in question (`state_two`) several times:

```
state: {
  current_state: 'state_two',
  transitions: [
    { from: 'state_two', to: 'state_one', at: [time in iso8601] },
    { from: 'state_one', to: 'state_two', at: [time in iso8601] },
    { from: 'state_two', to: 'state_one', at: [time in iso8601] },
    { from: 'state_one', to: 'state_two', at: [time in iso8601] }
  ]
}
```

In this case, when the `WHERE` clause matches on more than one of the `transitions` array elements, the query will return the same row several times. Is there an alternative way to structure this query such that all matching rows will only be returned once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (not tested):

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM json_array_elements(state->'transitions') state_changes(v)
    WHERE (
      (v->>'to' = 'state_two') AND 
      (v->>'at' < '2016-04-11 00:00:00.000000'))
  )
```

Hint: do not use JSON data type if you wish to use its elements in the SQL queries. Use tables/columns instead.